# Oracle SQL - Forcing execution plan with complex views

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have a view (let's call it "main_view") relying on another view on the same DB (view_1) and another view on another DB (accessed via db link, view_2).
For example:

```
create or replace view main_view as
select
    ...
from (
    select
        ...
    from (
        select
            case when (select xxx from view_1 z where z.id=a.id)='xxx' and ... then ...
                 when (select yyy from view_2 z where z.id=a.id)='yyy' and ... then ...
                 else ...
            end as c1,
            ...
        from table_1 a, table_2 b, ...
        where a.id=b.id and ...
    ) a
) a
```

If the main_view is used this way the performance are as good:

```
select * from main_view a where a.id in ('x','y',...)
```

But if the main_view is used like any of the following the performance are horrible (table_n contains 1k rows):

```
select a.* from main_view a, table_n b where a.id=b.id;
```

or

```
select * from main_view a where a.id in (select z.id from table_n z);
```

The execution plan show a couple table access storage full being executed (within the view).

Is there any way to force the execution plan to solve "everything but the main_view" and then join the main_view by id?

As a last resort I tried using hints like "ordered", "leading", "use_nl" and more but didn't succeed (maybe used the hints wrong).

```
select/*+leading(b a)*/ a.* from main_view a, table_n b where a.id=b.id;
select/*+no_merge(b)*/  a.* from main_view a, table_n b where a.id=b.id;
select/*+use_nl(b a)*/  a.* from main_view a, table_n b where a.id=b.id;
select/*+ordered*/      a.* from table_n b, main_view a where a.id=b.id;
```

Any idea?

The execution plan is 400+ rows and the real views are about 100+ rows too (and use the "with" clause, may be important to point it out).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try CTE with MATERIALIZE hint (opposite of INLINE hint) and also there is underscore parameter _complex_view_merging.

Comment: It sounds like you want the view to run a particular way no matter how it's accessed. In that case, you should hint within the view, not outside of it (i.e. put the "ordered" hint inside the view (and be sure the tables are in the correct order so it processes how you want) - or USE_NL or INDEX, etc - all these hints within the view). If, however, you want different plans depending on how the view is accessed, hinting within the view would hinder that.

Comment: @JimWartnick: thank you. I reproduced the problem on a simpler view and using a `+no_unnest(@block_name)` inside the view itself is working. Sorry for the late reply